# Prevent deep link in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my application I'd like to have certain portions of the app not be able to deep linked to. For example our users have a list of surveys and I'd like if someone tried to go directly to a particular survey directly such as `/survey/1` that react router would pick up on this and immediately redirect them back to `/survey` and they would have to select the one they want. I've tried to write `onEnter` hooks but they seem to be very cumbersome since the only way I've been able to get them to behave correctly is to store some global state that says they have been to the main page and inspect that every time the route is navigated to.

Im using pushstate in my application if that makes any difference and react-router 2.0

I'd like to try to avoid having to write server rewrite rules for this since there are a lot of areas in my application where this rule is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion which is similar to the `onEnter` hook:

- Wrap the component of the `survey/:id` route with a function which verifies if deep linking is allowed or not, let's call this function `preventDeepLinking`
- The `preventDeepLinking` function checks if the location state contains a certain flag, let's say `allowDeep`. This flag would be set in the location state when navigating from another page of your app. Obviously, this flag will not be set when the user tries to navigate directly to the page of a survey.
- The `preventDeepLinking` function will render the wrapped component only if deep linking is allowed, otherwise will redirect to a higher route.

I created a sample on codepen.io. You can play with it in the debug view of the Pen: http://s.codepen.io/alexchiri/debug/GZoRze.

In the debug view, click the Users link and then on a specific user from the list. Its name will be displayed below. Notice that its id is part of the url. Remove the hash including the `?_` and hit Enter. You will be redirected to `/users`.

The code of the Pen is here: http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/GZoRze

The `preventDeepLinking` function can be improved, but this is just to prove a point. Also, I would use the `browserHistory` in react-router but for some reason I couldn't get it running in codepen.

Hope this helps.